# zc.recipe.cmmi problems with plone on centos6

Tags: plone

I'm in trouble with zc.recipe.cmmi.
I'm trying to setup an enviroment with pound, without success.
When I lunch the buildout command I obtain:

```
Installing poundbuild.
poundbuild: compilation option :  --with-owner=root --with-group=root 
poundbuild: Downloading http://www.apsis.ch/pound/Pound-2.4.5.tgz
poundbuild: Unpacking and configuring
sh: ./configure: Permission denied
poundbuild: cmmi failed: /tmp/tmpbrKujvbuildout-poundbuild
While:
    Installing poundbuild.

An internal error occured due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/plone/portale/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.4-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1683, in main
getattr(buildout, command)(args)
File "/home/plone/portale/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.4-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 555, in install
installed_files = self[part]._call(recipe.install)
File "/home/plone/portale/eggs/zc.buildout-1.4.4-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1227, in _call
return f()
File "/home/plone/portale/eggs/plone.recipe.pound-0.5.5-py2.6.egg/plone/recipe/pound/build.py", line 78, in install
installed = CMMIRecipe.install(self)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/zc/recipe/cmmi/__init__.py", line 113, in install
self.build()
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/zc/recipe/cmmi/__init__.py", line 196, in build
self.cmmi(dest)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/zc/recipe/cmmi/__init__.py", line 221, in cmmi
system("%s %s" % (self.configure_cmd, options))
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/zc/recipe/cmmi/__init__.py", line 34, in system
raise SystemError("Failed", c)
SystemError: ('Failed', './configure --prefix=/home/plone/portale/parts/poundbuild  --with-owner=root --with-group=root ')
```

I've on my system all of the "development tools" installed.

Thank's all
Vito

Comment: You may want to include the buildout part config to make it clear what your setup is.

Comment: What was the solution to this, is it your pastebin in SteveM's comments section?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your system is configured to forbid execution of programs in the file system mounted as /tmp. You can change that, or temporarily use a different location for your temporary directory.

You may use a different location for temporary files by setting the TMP, TEMP and TEMPDIR environment variables. (Ideally, you'd only need one of those, but I've seen programs hard-wired to use each.)

Comment: Indeed. That's the case with Centos. Maybe the "shared" option can help avoid the /tmp/ issues.

Comment: Hi Steve, the problem is the zc.recipe.cmmi temp directory. Here the buildout's part: http://pastebin.com/drarBMBB

Comment: I was having a similar but different problem with Python 2.4 buildout & cmmi, and setting the various temp directories did not help.  Nor did sudo.  Never found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here:

```
sh: ./configure: Permission denied
```

Your user is not privileged enough to build Pound in this way. You may have to run buildout with sudo or as root to use the given configuration options "--with-owner=root --with-group=root"

Alternatively, you could change the 'owner' and 'group' variables in the 'poundbuild' part of your buildout.

Comment: Hi, I run the buildout as root.

Comment: Try checking the permissions on /tmp/tmpbrKujvbuildout-poundbuild/Pound-2.4.5/configure. Check that the user has permission to execute this file.